# Get price on Select input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get pricing from a **select** dropdown of three options. I've got a simple code (modified from a previous response to a different user in this forum) which works when the script is inline in the html document, but I just can't make it work through an external **.js** file.

```js
var drop = document.getElementById("persons");
var price = document.getElementById("tour-price");
drop.onchange = function() {
  price.innerHTML = drop.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="persons">
  <option value="" selected>Select the type of vehicle</option>
  <option value="US$197">On a SUV</option>
  <option value="US$255" >On a van</option>
  <option value="US$332" >On a minibus</option>
</select>
<p id="tour-price"><p/>
```

Comment: Please share the code that isn't working (the version in a separate file) as well

Comment: Is the imported script after the element? Or is it in the head?

Comment: It certainly looks OK (I added indentation, and removed the extraneous "</div>"  Q: Is the "external js" *IDENTICAL* to what you posted?  Q: How are you "running" the external .js, if not in a browser?  FYI, StackOverflow supports "code snippets".  You can literally add your executable JS to your post.

Comment: evolutionxbox, the imported script is in the 'head', as <script src="price.js"></script>

When I tried it inline, I had it at the end of the body.

Comment: paulsm4, Thank you! Though I've seen other questions with code snippets, I didn't know how to add them on my question (is the first time I ask one). I'll try to edit, now that I found the 'edit' link.

Comment: Can you check the js console and tell us if there are any error messages?

Comment: Dennishofken, it said getElementById undefined. I just fixed it, by moving the <script> to the end of the body (I had it in the head).

Comment: The `defer` keyworkd, like `<script defer src="path/to/script.js"></script` will wait until all the html is loaded before attempting to run the script, so you can have the script in the `<head>` section

Answer (score 0):

```
  ->  index.html
      |   js/main.js
```

If you have this folder structure, then simply put in tag <head>:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Make sure that permissions are ok, if you are on linux:

sudo chmod 755 js/main.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Fksjii!

I could make it work by putting the <script> at the end of the <body> instead of the <head>